# Azure AD B2C local account Sign-in page customization

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How is it possible to customize the translations for Azure AD B2C local account Sign-in page? Now it looks like this [image]

I have the same placeholder for username for all languages, which is wrong. When I do "User flows" -> "New user flow" -> "Sign in" -> "Standard" -> "Create" -> "Run user flow" - it opens this page, but when I select this user flow, "Languages" -> "Enable language customization" -> select language -> "Download defaults" - I can't find the text from this page there. How to replace this placeholder with correct text according to language?

**Edited:**
When I select the language for login page, I have this variants for editing:

[image]

Defaults of "Identity provider section page":

```
{
  "LocalizedStrings": [
    {
      "ElementType": "ClaimsProvider",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "AmazonExchange",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Amazon"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "ClaimsProvider",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "FacebookExchange",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Facebook"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "ClaimsProvider",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "GoogleExchange",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Google"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "ClaimsProvider",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "LinkedInExchange",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "LinkedIn"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "ClaimsProvider",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "MicrosoftAccountExchange",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Microsoft"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "ClaimsProvider",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "SignInWithLogonEmailExchange",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Local Account"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "ClaimsProvider",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "SignInWithLogonNameExchange",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Local Account"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "ClaimsProvider",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Email"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "ClaimsProvider",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "SignUpWithLogonNameExchange",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "User ID"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "alert_message",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Are you sure that you want to cancel choosing an identity provider?"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "alert_no",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "No"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "alert_title",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Cancel Selection"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "alert_yes",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Yes"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "already",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": ""
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "button_cancel",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Cancel"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "cancel_message",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "The user has canceled choosing an identity provider"
    },
    {
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "intro",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Sign in"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's correct to use [**language customization**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-user-flow). You could modify the value of this placeholder by changing the value of `UserId` in `LocalizedStrings`.

For example, I change the `Unified sign up or sign in page` of **English(en)** on my side.

[image]

```
{
  "ElementType": "ClaimType",
  "ElementId": "UserId",
  "StringId": "DisplayName",
  "Override": true,
  "Value": "Usernametest"
}
```

[image]

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: Hello. I have only 2 Page-level resource files, which are different than yours. I will add screenshot into my question

Comment: All values of "ElementId" = null; "ElementType": "ClaimType" - doesn't exist; "StringId": "DisplayName" - doesn't exist

Comment: Get it. That's because you use the [standard user flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-versions#standard-user-flows). **You can't customize the user interface with this user flow.** Please try with recommended user flows.

Comment: When I use "Recommended" variant of "Sign up and sign in", I can go throw all steps, which you discribe and I can see all the same on every step, but it still have no impact on result. I have overriden EN, CZ and PL languages, but there is no changes in Username placeholder: for browsers in CZ language it is "Uživatelské jméno / Username (email)", for browser in PL language it is "someone@example.com"