# How to override UxElement localized string based on a claim value

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am woring on an application, where header text comes from adb2c policy localization file.
I want to override {0} dynamically based on a claim type values.

```
<LocalizedResources Id="api.signuporsignin.en">
  <LocalizedStrings>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="local_intro_generic">Welcome to {0}</LocalizedString>
  </LocalizedStrings>
</LocalizedResources>
```

Is this possible, could someone please help me out?

Comment: Please check this it may help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids

Answer (score 2):

Placeholders like {0} will be filled automatically with the DisplayName value of ClaimType.

As sign up sign in has username and password by default, it cannot be changed if used in standard userflows.can be done in recommended flows.

We need to change what is to be filled by the user for the required claim type field and has to change html page content accordingly.

```
{
  "ElementType": "ClaimType",   //"UxElement"
  "ElementId": "UserId",    // ”<give original placeholder in your case >”
  "StringId": "DisplayName",//”<give original placeholder in your case >”local_intro_generic”
  "Override": true,
  "Value": "<required claim>"
}
```

Please check this Reference: [Azure AD B2C local account Sign-in page customization - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66619338/azure-ad-b2c-local-account-sign-in-page-customization)